# Apache Kafka alongside Confluent Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using the Azure HDInsight's managed *Apache* Kafka solution since unfortunately there's no managed Confluent Kafka solution on Azure. Is it possible to run the Confluent Schema Registry and connect it to the HDInsight Apache Kafka cluster's brokers?

I'm hoping to install just the Schema Registry on a single VM, then using this line in the schema-registry.properties file, point it to the HDInsight cluster's list of brokers:

kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

Will this work? Or do the brokers need to be Confluent installations and not Apache?

Comment: Are you able to point me to a resource where you think *Confluent Platform* is **not** *Apache Kafka*? I would really like to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @cricket_007 Since HDInsight Kafka doesn't include any of the Confluent features in it, that lead me down the wrong path of thinking that they may be two different set of Kafka implementations. I now realize that Confluent sits on top of Apache Kafka and only adds features to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache Kafka brokers in Confluent Platform *are* Apache Kafka. So yes you can self-host Schema Registry and connect it to Apache Kafka from another distribution.

Comment: So this means kafka identifies configuration `confluent.schema.registry.url` and it is not specific to confluent platform? Couldn't find any documentation in kafka regarding this.

Comment: Please post a new question if you have one :)

Comment: Asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832588/does-kafka-support-schema-registries-out-of-the-box-or-is-it-a-confluent-platfo