# Does kafka support schema registries out of the box, or is it a confluent platform feature?

Tags: apache-kafka

I came across the following article on how to use the schema registry available in the confluent platform.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema-validation.html

According to that article, we can specify `confluent.schema.registry.url` in `server.properties` to point Kafka to the schema registry.

My question is, is it possible to point a Kafka cluster which is not a part of confluent platform deployment, to a schema registry using `confluent.schema.registry.url`?

Comment: Clients can use the schema registry url with Kafka as part of serialization. The feature you found is for server-side message validation

Comment: @OneCricketeer can you please point me the client config to be used for pointing a kafka client (consumer and producer) to a schema registry?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema_registry_onprem_tutorial.html#schema-registry-onprem-tutorial

Comment: Also, more detailed guide https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/installing-and-upgrading-the-kafka-schema-registry-2b2944a22244

Comment: @OneCricketeer in your first link, kafka client is pointed to the schema registry by setting `schema.registry.url` in `$HOME/.confluent/java.config`. It feels like this is something confluent specific. Would it work if I just specify `schema.registry.url` in `props` of consumer and producer?

Comment: The `confluent` cli command is specific, but the Java config file is not. So, that's right, assuming you're pulling `kafka-avro-serializer` dependency (assuming Java) and using the appropriate serailizers. Refer [Same page](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema_registry_onprem_tutorial.html#client-applications-writing-avro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-side schema validation is part of Confluent Server, not Apache Kafka.

I will make sure that that docs page gets updated to be more clear - thanks for raising it.